# Creating multiple components using ReactJS in Sharepoint online

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

as I'm new to developing Sharepoint online using ReactJS, I have been trying to look ways to use react components in Sharepoint online as the same as normal ReactJS websites. I mean, If I want to create another component that makes it easy to maintain instead of writing the whole logics, codes... inside just one file. So If there's anyone experienced in Sharepoint online with React please give me an example ^^ Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked out some tutorials online on the subject ("react", "sharepoint", "spfx")? I mean, what is your question exactly?

Comment: @Nikolay yep, I mean I want to create multiple components in sharepoint online, It is as the same as normal websites using react

Comment: If you are asking if it is possible, then yes, it is possible :) Take a look at the SharePoint SPFx framework, which is built to help you with this. Was this this question?